# How to select entire column if there is a text match in columns and move to a specific sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet which generate different column names every time, but has the same starting word.

So for example, I could have a column with the name "Key" , after 2 to three columns there would columns with names as key3,key29 likewise I have another word called value and then value1,value2 after some columns value6,value7 etc

What I want to do is to search the columns names in the sheet Rows("1:1").Select and select the entire column if a text matches to the value I assign and finally copy it to separate sheet.

So far this is what I tried.

```
Rows("1:1").Select 'Selecting the columns row
' Finding values with name i want to look for
Selection.Find(What:="key", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate.Select
```

Comment: what is your actual question? it's unclear what you are actually have a problem with. i also don't see any code that attempts to complete your objective

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To clarify, the first two paragraphs of your question are irrelevant, correct, or am I missing something? What happens when you run your code? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) for the `Range` object and scan through the list of mehods and properties.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman    I am looking to loop through the column names and select only the column names which matches the word even partially, if i specify the word to look for is 'Key' then it should select all column names that contain the word key in it and move to another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    SearchString = "Test"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Rows("1")

        For Each cell In rng.Cells

            If InStr(1, cell.Value, SearchString) > 0 Then

                LastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                .Columns(cell.Column).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(LastColumn + 1)
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this will fail to find `Test1` for example and its also going to search the whole used range, and not just the column headers in row1

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give a great start. Adjust any worksheet, cell and range references as needed. There's also a ton of resources on what each method I used does in case anything is unfamiliar to you.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")' change as needed

    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'change column as needed

    Dim headers as Range
    Set headers = .Range("A1",.Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    Dim findIt as String
    findIt = "key"

    Dim cel as Range
    For each cel in headers
        If cel.Text like "*key*" Then 
            .Range(cel,.Cells(lastRow, cel.Column)).Copy worksheets("sheet2").Cells(1,cel.Column) 'change sheet and column as needed
        End if
   Next

End With
```

Comment: .range method in the if condition shows as red @ScottHoltzman

Comment: fixed in answer @Ahmed